# int data type in Go

Tags: go, int

I am new to Go language and was trying out few examples in GO.
In GO int is not a keyword so I declared a variable with name as `int`.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var int int = 8
    fmt.Println(int)

    var number int = 10
    fmt.Println(number)
}
```

Now when I build this code I get following error:

```
[dev@go test]$ go build variables.go
# command-line-arguments
./variables.go:8: int is not a type
```

I am trying to understand the reason why this is seen and what did `var int int` do such that int becomes an unavailable data type.

Comment: You gave the answer to your question: You made `int` something different (which is possible as it is not a keyword) and now it is something different.

Comment: Yes! It seems like the behavior of int changed. Here I was overwriting "int object" and in the next lines set int type for another variables, because in `int` now I have only value 8, not "int object".

Comment: @Adrian: It's a predeclared numeric type, but AFAIK, you still can do something like `int := struct{}`. Sad, but true. What the OP should accept is that most languages allow you to do bad things, it's up to you not to do so. It's like writing bad C, invoking/relying on undefined behaviour. It's possible, but it's not something you should be doing

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // int is a predeclared type identifier
    var int int = 8
    // int is a variable identifier
    fmt.Println(int)

    // error: int is not a type
    var number int = 10
    fmt.Println(number)
}
```

You are shadowing the `int` identifier.

See [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Go is a block structured programming language:

[Blocks](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks)

[Declarations and scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

`int` is a [predeclared identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers) and is implicitly declared in the universe block.

The scope of a variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the declaration and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.

The statement

```
var int int = 8
```

uses the predeclared `int` type to declare a variable identifier `int`, shadowing the predeclared identifier: [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 0):

In Go int is a predefined identifier, therefore it cannot be used as a variable name. So rename the first variable to anything else. Such as num1 and it will compile!

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num1 int = 8
    fmt.Println(num1)

    var number int = 10
    fmt.Println(number)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even if I remove my last 2 lines, still it compiles. So was not getting why does this happen. It accepts int as variable name but changes behavior of data type int.

Comment: @bhagyeshdudhediya Hmm, that is interesting alright. I assume the compiler sees that there is no other int instantiated so there is no other way to interpret the code? (If there is no other int variable, the only possibility is that you wanted to create an int called int.)

Comment: @Deancoakley: ALERT: "in Go you cannot use the reserve word int as a variable name." Not true. `int` is a [predecared identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers). 'int' is not a reserved [keyword](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords).

Comment: @peterSO What's the difference between predeclared identifier and a keyword. So in Go typing int actually refers to an object or package or something? I am reading `Keywords are used to recognize the type/kind of entity and identifier is used to uniquely name that entity.` isn't that exactly what int is doing here?